# Java generics: Returning a list depending on input

Tags: java, generics

For example I've the classes A, B, C and they are all in a `List<Object>` (The list is from an XML-Parser and I have no influence on this part). Usually I need only one type. So I've written the following class:

```
public class FilterForObject{
public static List<A> extractA(Result r){
  return extractClass(r,A.class);
}
public static List<B> extractB(Result r){
  return  extractClass(r,B.class);
}
public static List<C> extractC(Result r){
  return  extractClass(r,C.class);
}

private static <T> List<T> exctracClass(final Result r,final Class<T> resultClass) {
    List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>(40);
    for (Object o : r.getAorBorC()) {
        if( o instanceof T){
            ret.add((T)o); // For some reasons this doesn't work
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

}
```

I've run into the following warning:

> Cannot perform instanceof check against type parameter T. Use its erasure Object instead since further generic type information will be erased at runtime

But I don't get the exact problem, at compile time all the possible return types were known?

Comment: A method doesn't really "know" what type parameter it was called with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But i don't get the exact problem, at runtime all the possible return types were known?

No, at runtime the type of `T` is *not* known, due to *type erasure*. The compiler can't do anything useful with either casts or the `instanceof` operator.

However, as you've already got a parameter `Class<T> resultClass` you can use:

```
if (resultClass.isInstanceOf(o))) {
    ret.add(resultClass.cast(o));
}
```

For more about type erasure (and generics in general) see the [Java generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#Topic3).

Answer (score 3):

You're already passing in the type token for the generic type parameter, you can (and have to) use that instead of compiler-generated casts:

```
private static <T> List<T> exctracClass(final Result r,final Class<T> resultClass) {
    List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>(40);
    for (Object o : r.getAorBorC()) {
        if(resultClass.isInstance(o)){
            ret.add(resultClass.cast(o));
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have the Class of the expected result, you can do the following :

```
private static <T> List<T> extractClass(final Result r, final Class<T> resultClass) {
    List<T> ret = new ArrayList<T>(40);
    for (Object o : r.getAorBorC()) {
        if (resultClass.isInstance(o)) {
            ret.add((T) o); // For some reasons this doesn't work
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

All the operations that you can do on classes and instances that are supported by some special constructs (instanceof, casting...), you can also do via methods on the Class object : isInstance, cast, asSubclass...